# objective-C creating an app with GPS and specific shop finder

Tags: objective-c, gps, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm a VERY new coder. I made 3 apps so far but i'm not satisfied with those apps (They're too easy to make). I recently had an idea, locating the closest gas station and displaying the cheapest one near the user. Now, i know it's possible i just don't know the steps in order to put this app together. iPhoneSDK wasn't helpful, most reply i got was something like "Go read this book to learn the whole objective-C language". All i want is someone to guide me in the right direction. I'm pretty sure i need some kind of database to do an app like that, That's all i know.
Again, if you're going to answer something like: "This app can't be made by a beginner", please don't even bother commenting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is getting downvoted because you're asking an extremely large scale question that comes across as "How do I build my app".  There are millions of ways to answer this question, but the decisions need to be made by you.  This app CAN be made by a beginner, if you're patient, persistent, and resourceful.  Break your larger problems into smaller segments and learn those one by one.  Something like this would be a way to break down your problem.

Step 1: Google "How to find user's location in iOS"

Step 2: Google "Gas station api" this was literally the first result:

http://www.mygasfeed.com/keys/api

Step 3: Google "How to make an HTTP request in iOS"

Step 4: Google "How to use JSON in iOS"

Step 5: Put them all together.

Comment: I knew Stack overflow wasn't the best place to ask something like this but i was desperate. Thankfully you replied and gave me hope! Thank you!

Comment: Good luck with your project, don't give up!